# How to retrieve a GET variable with a hash in it

Tags: python, django

I have the following variable that is passed in a url:

http://localhost:8000/diff/?Platform=Comcast&PlatformID=7066191365225244112#S8

I need to be able to extract the following:

```
Platform = Comcast
PlatformID = 7066191365225244112#S8
```

However, django will escape the hash in the request.GET dictionary. Here is what it shows:

```
GET:<QueryDict: {u'PlatformID': [u'7066191365225244112'], u'Platform': [u'Comcast']}>,
```

How would I capture the full variable here, including the `#S8` at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape it in the query string, basically replace the hash with %23.

To answer your question in the comments, yes, there is a template tag that can help you with this. The syntax is

```
{% url 'some-url-name' arg1=v1 arg2=v2 %}
```

Or, if you want to escape in code, you have several options in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.encoding

Comment: thank you, is there a django template tag or something that will escape characters like this and do a urlencode?